# database(mongoose) configuration for production in node

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i am new to nodejs. I want to set up database(mongoose) configuration for production in a separate file same as we use properties file in java. Please help me with some example.

Comment: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv https://github.com/dominictarr/rc https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config

Comment: @robertklep helpful thanks!

Comment: @robertklep what about using nconf ???

Comment: Whatever fits you best, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [node-config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config)

as best practice, you will have to create a `config` folder with config files corresponding to your NODE_ENV

for example, if you have three env:

- `development`: local development host
- `production`: production host
- `staging`: staging host

you'll have to create 3 files plus a `default.js` config file, `node-config` will override default settings with the config file corresponding to NODE_ENV

#### config/default.js

```
module.exports = {
  // node port
  port: 3000
  // other default settings
};
```

#### config/development.js

```
module.exports = {
  // mongo url
  mongoUrl: "mongodb://localhost/db"
};
```

#### config/production.js

```
module.exports = {
  // mongo url
  mongoUrl: "mongodb://production.mongo.host/db"
};
```

#### config/staging.js

```
module.exports = {
  // mongo url
  mongoUrl: "mongodb://staging.mongo.host/db"
};
```